# HTML Form submit not displaying the javascript output

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I wish to have a submit button (for the default form action), and an additional button for a second action.

I have the following code:

```
<html>
<head><title></title>
<?PHP
$Input = "";
if(isset($_POST['Input'])) $Input = $_POST['Input'];
?>
</head>

<body>
    <FORM id ="form1" method="post">
        Input: <INPUT TYPE = "TEXT" VALUE ="<?php echo $Input;?>" NAME = "Input" SIZE="3">
        <INPUT TYPE = "submit" id = "action1" VALUE = "action 1"> 
        <INPUT TYPE = "button" id = "action2" VALUE = "action 2">
    </FORM>
    <br>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var form = document.getElementById('form1'); 

        form.onsubmit = function() {
            document.getElementById("php_code_action1").innerHTML="<?php echo "action 1<br>"; ?>";
            document.getElementById("php_code_action2").innerHTML="";
        };

        document.getElementById('action2').onclick = function() 
        {     
            document.getElementById("php_code_action2").innerHTML="<?php echo "action 2<br>"; ?>";
            document.getElementById("php_code_action1").innerHTML="";
        } 
    </script>

    <span id="php_code_action1"> </span>
    <span id="php_code_action2"> </span>

</body>
</html>
```

A click on the Action2 button works as I expect, but a click on "Action1" button has the page refresh and the output of action1 disappear.

Why is there a refresh, and how can I show the output of action1?

Comment: This is a rather confused question. Is it about HTML, Javascript or PHP? Can you narrow down your question to one technology please?

Comment: You are right: I was confused. Problem was either html or javascript (not php). Turned out you gave a fix on the javascript part. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
form.onsubmit = function() {
    document.getElementById("php_code_action1").innerHTML="<?php echo "action 1<br>"; ?>";
    document.getElementById("php_code_action2").innerHTML="";
    return false;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write `return false;` in your `onsubmit` handler to prevent the usual action, i.e. form submission. Then the page shouldn't "refresh".